# Passing attributes to shader

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I am using OPEN GL ES2.0 on Android.

I need pass two attributes to shader, one for position, one for texture coordinates,

```
//vertices for position
vertices = new float[12] { -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f };

//vertices for texture coordinates.
txtVertices = new float[12] { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };


//Passing to shader.
    glVertexAttribPointer(texCoordHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
        txtVertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(vPositionHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);


glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPositionHandle);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordHandle);


glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(vPositionHandle);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(texCoordHandle);
```

What's the problem of this piece of code? it's like the second one override the first one, and only one vertices are passed into my shader.

Comment: Without seeing your shader code, it is not possible to know. Furthermore, please post the piece of code where you retrieve the handles to shader attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that ther is no error in the code you posted.

may have errors in shaders or in some other part

don't you pass 3 floats for vertexposition(x,y,z)